# connection with Android and Jaybird driver

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jdbc

I'm having a problem in creating an android connection with Firebird database, when I execute the app doesn't crash, but it's not returning any result, I know the problem is when executes the line of connection.

Here is my code :

```js
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                try{
                    Class.forName("org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver").newInstance();
                    System.err.println("jdbc created");
                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.err.println("Cannot create connection");
                    Toast.makeText(cntx, "erreur inisialisation", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
  
                try {
                  
                    Properties props = new Properties();
                    props.setProperty("user", "SYSDBA");
                    props.setProperty("password", "masterkey");
                    props.setProperty("encoding", "WIN1252");
                  
                    try {

                        System.err.println("creating connection");
                        java.sql.Connection connection =                DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:firebirdsql:192.168.1.4:C:\\TEST.FDB", props);
                        System.err.println("created connection");
                      
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.err.println("error in connection to server");
                        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                        Log.v("TRACKKK", "Result : " + e.getMessage() + "  //  Localized message : " + e.getLocalizedMessage() + "  //  trace : " + e.getStackTrace());
                        Toast.makeText(cntx, "problem connexion", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                  

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err.println("error in connection to server");
                    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(cntx, "Server Not Connected, Mybe your adress ip is wrrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
  
            }

 });
```

This is the message in logcat of Android Studio:

```js
05-24 12:20:18.268 27712-27712/com.formation.uk2015.testfirebird W/System.err: jdbc created
05-24 12:20:18.268 27712-27712/com.formation.uk2015.testfirebird W/System.err: creating connection
05-24 12:20:18.568 27712-27722/com.formation.uk2015.testfirebird W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.689ms
05-24 12:20:18.568 27712-27712/com.formation.uk2015.testfirebird D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet+,hn 11(0x3139322e313638),sn(),hints(known),family 0,flags 4
05-24 12:20:18.568 27712-27712/com.formation.uk2015.testfirebird D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet-, SUCCESS
05-24 12:20:18.568 27712-27712/com.formation.uk2015.testfirebird W/System.err: error in connection to server
05-24 12:20:18.568 27712-27712/com.formation.uk2015.testfirebird W/System.err: null
05-24 12:20:18.568 27712-27712/com.formation.uk2015.testfirebird V/TRACKKK: Result : null  //  Localized message : null  //  trace : [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@2d9311c0
```

I use [http://sourceforge.net/projects/androidjaybird/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ehDB.jpg) as a driver 
I have include the libs and assets folder to my project :

app->

-assets

- libs->

  - Jaybird2_2_4.jar.

[Here is the strucrure of Asset and Jaybird driver added to my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ehDB.jpg)

But I didn't have any problem when i created this project in eclipse